# how to find stolen device location in iOS sdk?

Tags: ios, objective-c, icloud

My requirement is to get theft device location in iOS sdk, it is possible by using https://www.icloud.com/#find with apple id, but can we get these information using iOS sdk.

Comment: Wouldn't someone just use Find My iPhone app in iCloud to track their stolen device? Why would they need to use your app ?

Comment: even i thought the same, but its a clients requirement

Answer (score 0):

The location service is related with user's privacy...
I don't think you are able to achieve this information from Apple

Comment: what if user permits to access?

Comment: But you cannot guarantee that a user would not use the app to track other's phone if there is any user privacy access within the sdk. To protect user information, the device's location will only be available to the user that own's the Apple account for such device

Answer (score 0):

Apple provides no API for this, so there's no way for third party apps to access this data.